# Send outside of loop but after callback - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, callback, request

If I have a loop that makes `i` number of requests like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  request(array[i], (error, response, body) => {
    arrayToSend.push(body)
  })
}
```

now I want to send my array to the user like this:

```
res.send(JSON.stringify(arrayToSend));
```

This would seem like it *should* work, but if `request` takes to long then you end up with an empty array. I cannot put `res.send()` into the `request` callback, because then it would send it `i` number of times which would be no good.

I am wondering how I can call `res.send()` once, only after all the requests have been made.

Comment: try reutrn res.send() because return keyword stops the execution after returning the value.Otherwise use res.end() function.

Comment: I used `res.end()` and it worked great! thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, glad it worked!